# Prove that $\tan(\sin^{-1}(-t))=-\tan(\sin^{-1}(t))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is there anyway to prove this equality:
$$\tan(\sin^{-1}(-t))=-\tan(\sin^{-1}(t))\, ?$$

Having a hard time trying to start this question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Let $\sin^{-1}(-t)=u,$

$-t=\sin u,t=-\sin u=\sin(-u),\sin^{-1}t=-u$